# Updating Sharepoint list multi-choice field with excel VBA SQL code

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql, vba, syntax

For a given sharepoint list, I am trying to create a row via an SQL statement.

My SQL statement is as follows:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO `My Sharepoint List` (`Title`, `Lead`, `Part`) VALUES ('Project1', 'LeaderPerson', 'Part1;#Part2')
```

The last of these three data items, `Part`, is a multi-choice field in Sharepoint.

The solutions I've read online for updating this field will not work. Users have suggested adding ";" to the start and end of the value, or adding ";#" to the start and end of the value string. I cannot get even a single value to populate the field using ";", ";#" or any combination thereof including using brackets "[]".

Is there another method someone has come across for updating Sharepoint multi-choice fields. The query executes but this field is always blank.